# Java Desktop Application which connects to Facebook

Tags: java, facebook-java-api, facebook-java-sdk

I have to develop a Java application which connects to Facebook and allows me to sign in and chat with my friends. I did a lot of research on the internet but I couldn't find a way to do it, so please can someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/

http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/facebook-java-api-example-to-publish-on-wall/

Try typing in google words like "facebook api java example" ...

Comment: I encountered a problem. In their tutorial it appears that it is generated : Application ID, API key,Secret. If I follow the links, It generates for a new application only : APP_ID, APP_SECRET. For obtaining the access token I need the API_KEY, I cannot find it anywhere. Excuse my bad english

Comment: in the second tutorial it's shown - 3 lines with 3 keys. what do you have in API_KEY line instead? Also look at this: http://www.blog.web6.org/how-to-get-facebook-api-key/ and here http://www.khawaib.co.uk/forum/2-ka-facebook-fanbox-pro/5813-cant-find-my-api-key.html